# $_POST returns empty after html form submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I just started learning php today (this is basically copy/pasted from the w3schools tutorial).

This is the html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And this is the php file:

```
<html>
<body> 
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>    
<br>    
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>    
</body>
</html>
```

I've downloaded xampp but when I try to submit the form, I get the following:

> Welcome
>
> Your email address is:

So it seems like `$_POST` is empty... any ideas why this might be? Thanks!

EDIT: Moved the files to the xampp htdocs folder, it works now. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Check to see if the inputs are entered using `isset` before `echo`ing.

Comment: You can also `var_dump($_POST)` or `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see if any values exist at all.

Comment: have you input something in those text fields?

Comment: webserver/PHP installed? accessed how as `http://yourhost/file.xxx` or as `c://file.xxx`? those are 2 different animals altogether.

Comment: If you view the source are the PHP blocks in the code?

Comment: Your PHP script file or any script with PHP code in it must have a `.php` extension. Beware, if you are using `notepad.exe` it adds a `.txt` extension so your file may be names `xxxxx.php.txt` Dont use notepad to edit php source

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, it does have a .php extension.

Comment: @chris85 yes, the php blocks are in the code (for the page I get after submitting)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I access the file by double clicking the .html file, and I think xampp includes php?

Comment: So you double `.html` on your desktop (or wherever) and it opens in a browser as `http` or `file:///`? I don't know windows well but it sounds like you are bypassing the PHP processing in your current execution flow.

Comment: You're not accessing your pages through your web server (xampp)

Comment: Run the page from your browser like any other web page, using `localhost/file.php` or if you have the script in a subfolder of htdocs use `localhost/subfolder/file.php` Unless you do this the PHP compiler will not be invoked